# How many five-digit numbers can be formed using digits $0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8,9$ which are divisible by $3$ and $5$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many five-digit numbers can be formed using digits $0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8$ and $9$ which are divisible by $3$ and $5$, **without any of the digits repeating**?

For the number to be divisible by $5$ it must end with $0$ (or $5$, but we don't have it in the given problem). So we have $V_6^4$ numbers which are divisible by $5$ but how can we exclude those which aren't divisible by $3$?

> $120$

Comment: Which combinations of the numbers are divisible by $3$? Worry about the permutations later.

Comment: $\sum \{1,2,6,7,8,9\} = 33$ which is divisible by $3$, so the two excluded digits will need to sum to a multiple of $3$. Find all such pairs.

Comment: "but how can we exclude these which aren't divisible by 3"  By knowing that a number is divisible by $3$ iff and only if the sum of the digits are a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @Joffan You are assming you must use each digit at most once.  That is not a requirement.

Comment: $0 , 1 , 2 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9  $ mod 3 is $0, 1 , 2 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 0$. Now $3$ must divide sum. Partition cases as how many numbers of type $0$ mod 3, $1$ mod 3 and $2$ mod 3 you pick. Also remember, leftmost digit cannot be 0.

Comment: The statement does not rule out repetition of digits?

Comment: @fleablood yes it is a requirement, "without any digits repeating"

Comment: Oh!  Well that makes things a *LOT* easier.

Comment: @fleablood I think the opposite happens.

Comment: @Jorge you think disallowing repition of digits makes thing *harder*?

Comment: @fleablood yes. If you allow repetition it is $2\cdot7^3$ because you pick the leftmost digit last and there are two options for each congruence mod 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must select the $5$ digits which must appear, although we know the $0$ must appear. So in reality we must only select $4$ digits out of $6$ possibilities.

Notice the sum of all those numbers is a multiple of $3$ ($1+2+6+7+8+9 = 33)$. Therefore the condition is that the two numbers we do not pick add up to a multiple of $3$.

There are $4$ possible ways to do this if these numbers are $1$ and $2\bmod 3$ and there is one option when both unselected numbers are multiples of $3$.

We conclude there are $5$ valid selections for the $5$ digits that appear. For each configuration there are $4!$ rearrangements.

We conclude the answer is $5\times 4! = 120$

Comment: I didn't get why "the condition is that the two numbers we do not pick add up to a multiple of $3$".

Comment: we want the $4$ numbers we do select to add up to a multiple of $3$ this is equivalent to the $2$ numbers we do not select to also add up to a multiple of $3$ (because the $6$ numbers in total also add up to a multiple of $3$)

Comment: Thank you! I haven't studied about $\bmod$. What does it mean?

Comment: We say a number is $0\bmod 3$ if it of the form $3k$. We say a number is $1\bmod 3$ if it is of the form $3k+1$. We say a number is $2\bmod 3$ if it is of the form $3k+2$. I recommend you look into it when you can. It isn't a very complicated concept but it is useful notation.

Comment: So a number is $0\bmod 3$ basically means the number is divisible by $3$ or it is a multiple of $3$?

Comment: yes exactly.${}{}$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

$0$ is last digit. Note that there are only 2 numbers from the set whose mod 3 is 1.

**Case 1**: Pick $0$ $x$ s.t. $x \mod 3 = 1$: Not possible

**Case 2**: Pick exactly 1 digit x s.t. $x \mod 3 = 1$. We must pick exactly 1 digit x s.t. $x \mod 3 = 2$. Remaining are filled with $x \mod 3 = 0$.

Sum = $2 * 2 * (4!) = 96$

**case 3**: Pick 2 digits x  s.t. $x \mod 3 = 1$: We must pick exactly 2 digits x s.t. $x \mod 3 = 2$.

Sum = $4! = 24$

Ans = $96 + 24 = 120$

Comment: @Troposphere made a mistake earlier, edited now.

Comment: Looks good +1, although to be completely honest I think it isn't immediately clear those are all the cases.

Comment: There are only $2$ numbers from the set whose mod $3$ is 1.

Comment: I understand why, I'm just saying it isn't immediately clear.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll edit the answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The two divisiblity rules you are assumed to use are: Divisible by $5$ if and only if last digit is $0$ or $5$ and; divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits add to a multiple of $3$.

Divisble by $5$ means last digit is $0$.  That's the only option.

Divisble by $3$ means that first four digits, lets call them $a,b,c,d$ add up to a multiple of $3$

We have already used $0$ so there we must pick from the remaining $6$ for digits that add to a multiple of $3$.

Insight is... we must remove $2$ and which $2$ can we remove?  Suppose we keep $a,b,c,d$ and remove $e,f$.  Then $a+b+c+d$ must be a multiple of $3$ and $(a+b+c+d) +(e+f) = 1+2+6 + 7 + 8 +9 = 33$. So we must have $e+f = 33 -$ a multiple of $3=$ a multiple of $3$.

So we can have $e$ and $f$ be $6$ and $9$ the only two multiples of $3$.  Or we can have $e$ or $f$ be a pair that aren't multiples of three but add to multiples of $3$.  That would mean one has remainder of $1$ and the other has a remainder of $2$. So one is $\{1,7\}$ then other is $\{2,8\}$.  So that is $4$ possible pairs.  Or it could be $\{e,f\}=\{6,9\}$ make $5$ possible pairs.

(If that was too confusing.  To have $e+f$ be a multiple of $3$ we can have $\{e,f\} = (1,2), (1,8), (7,2), (7,8), (6,9)$.  Five options. And $a,b,c,d$ can be...everything left.  Five options:  $(6,7,8,9), (2,6,7,9) ,(1,6,8,9),(1,2,6,9), (1,2,7,8)$.)

So there are $5$ choices for $(a,b,c,d)$ and there are $4! = 24$ ways to arrange them and there is only one option for the last digit.  There are $5*24 =120$ such numbers.

Comment: I still don't get why $e+f$ must be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Because $(a+b+c+d) +(e+f) = 33$ is a multiple of $3$.  And $(a+b+c+d) = 3k$ is a multiple of $3$.  So $(e+f) = 33 -3k = 3(11-k)$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Thank you! A really nice explanation! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To be divisible by $5$, the five-digit number must end in $0$. There are $360=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$ integers that can be made by arranging four of the available non-zero digits before the zero. These $360$ five-digit numbers might have remainder $0$, $1$, or $2$ when divided by $3$, and since the six available digits are equally distributed modulo $3$ (two of each possibility mod $3$), each of the three possible remainders is equally likely among the $360$ possible five-digit numbers. Therefore exactly one third of them, or $120$, are divisible by $3$.

Comment: Can you explain why we know there must be symmetry in the number of outcomes? Or which are the conditions which are being used to get that symmetry?

Comment: Oh I guess you are using the fact that $4$ and $3$ are coprime and you can add $1$ to each element of a $4$-set. So $(a,b,c,d),(a+1,b+1,c+1,d+1),(a+2,b+2,c+2,d+2)$ gives a full residue class for every $(a,b,c,d)$. Cool solution

Comment: The jump I didn’t carefully justify is that if the digits are uniformly distributed modulo 3, so are the size-4-subset-sums of those digits. At first, I didn’t think the number $4$ mattered, but actually it does, since the size-$6$-subset-sums are not equi-distributed. Good observation!

Comment: Yeah, I think the reasoning I gave works for $n$-subset-sums $\mod m$ when $n$ and $m$ are coprime.

Comment: I should probably think about that! My thinking was really a quick “Well, how could there be any bias in the distribution of the subset sums?” but of course, there can.