# How many five-digit numbers can be formed using digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$ which are divisible by $3$ and $5$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many five-digit numbers can be formed using digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$ which are divisible by $3$ and $5$, without any of the digits repeating?

A number is divisible by $5$ if and only if last digit is $0$ or $5$ and; divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits add to a multiple of $3$ ($3,6,9,12,15,18,21$).

Divisible by $5$ means last digit is $5$. That's the only option.

Divisible by $3$ means that the sum of the digits add up to a multiple of $3$.

What can we do next? It's difficult for me to find the 5-tuples just by looking at the given digits? What can I do to systematize them and not miss some?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many five-digit numbers can be formed using digits $0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8,9$ which are divisible by $3$ and $5$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084536/how-many-five-digit-numbers-can-be-formed-using-digits-0-1-2-6-7-8-9-whic)

Comment: Wonder what's so special about 3 and 5, that you get 500 questions on this topic. When they start asking divisibility on 7 and 19, that would be interesting.

Comment: @Kaind, aren't we allowed to ignore every topic we want? I am completely fine with $500!$ questions like this. The author has shown effort.

Comment: @Kaind: It's definitely _special_ about 3 and 5 that the divisibility tests treat all digit positions (except one, in the case of 5) uniformly such that the counting methods employed in the answers work at all.

Comment: @Katherine I wasn't dismissing it.. If you check the link to posted by Troposphere, I was one of the answerers too.. I was wondering how two (almost entirely same) questions were asked by two independant people in such a short space of time.

Comment: If nothing else, it's a bit of fresh air compared to the usual pointless "how many words can I form from ANTIDISESTABLISHMENTARIANISM such that no two vowels are next to each other" type exercises.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

The mostright digit should be $ 5$.

now, we have to choose $ 4 $ digits from $5 $. there are five possibilities
$$\{1,2,3,4\}\;;\;\{1,3,4,6\}\;;\;\{1,2,4,6\}\;;\;\{2,3,4,6\}\;;\;\{1,2,3,6\}$$

take those for which the (sum +5) is divisible by $ 3$.

we find
$$\{1,2,4,6,5\}\;;\;\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$

The final answer is $2\times 4!=48$.